# below code not executed after second time

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   
    char ans='y';
    int i=1;
    while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y'){
        printf("\n%d,",i);
        i++;
        printf("\nDo you want to Print another value of i?");
        scanf("%c",&ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1,
> Do you want to Print another value of i?Y
> 2,
> Do you want to Print another value of i?Y
> dash: 2: Y: not found

Comment: The second time through, you're picking up the newline character (from the "enter" key).  It's seeing `Y\nY\n`.  You need to consume the newlines.

Comment: Print ans after scan f, to see what's in it.

Comment: Note: I've switched this to C++ as you're using a C++ header,  if you really want C you should be using `<stdio.h>` instead and a C compiler

Answer (score 1):

```c
scanf("%c",&ans);
```

Reads character by character including white characters.
So after first `y` when you press enter then next character read is `\n`.

Discard white characters and it will work as you expect, so fix this like this (note extra space before `%c`):

```c
scanf(" %c",&ans);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Gd5Eo7boq